# Track a single anchor link in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, anchor

My client's website includes multiple product pages. On each, there is an option to "Contact Sales". This option is an anchor link that changes the screen to show the salesperson's contact information. The structure looks like this:

"http://www.example.com/products/detail/product-1.html" is the product page.

"http://www.example.com/products/detail/product-1.html#contactsales" is the anchor link that makes the sales information appear. The URL doesn't change.

I would like to track as a conversion any time someone clicks the "Contact Sales" anchor link on any product page. I have seen some solutions that will track all anchor link clicks, but I don't want to track any anchor links other than "Contact Sales", and then only as conversions. What is the easiest way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be easiest if you attach your event directly to the anchor:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/products/detail/product-1.html#contactsales" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Contact Sales', 'click');">Contact Sales</a>
```

Then you would be able to create an event goal around that.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to target a single product page. I would like to track as a conversion any time someone clicks the "Contact Sales" anchor link on any product page (there are several hundred).

Comment: Either you put the code on every page, or write a listener that gets added to all pages, or you use GTM. I'm leaning on GTM. It'll be better in the long run because it's scalable.